# Form submit to run javascript and then post to php script

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently working on a php/html/javascript project. I have a form where when the user presses the submit button, it should run a javascript function and then afterwards post to a php page to process the data that was submitted in the form.

I have the form run a javascript method as below

```
<form class="form" id="addImageForm" name="addImageForm" action="javascript:validateAddImage();" method="post">
```

The method validates the form, calls another method and then it submits the form using `document.myForm.submit();`

How do I get it to submit the form to another php page to process the data including upload selected files.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just pass your page name into action tag and call javascript function on onsubmit event of your form.
<form class="form" id="addImageForm" name="addImageForm" action="yourpage.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateAddImage();">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set yout 'action' parameter to your PHP script, and do any javascript procesing in a javascript event.

```
<form class="form" id="addImageForm" name="addImageForm" action="processing.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateAddImage();">
```

Then in your js validation, return 'true' if everything's fine, or 'false' if not. Returning 'true' means 'continue with the submit process and send over data to processing.php

Comment: No problem, I had to face this problem many times. You can also look into jQuery validation plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 5):

What you need is [onsubmit](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html).

```
<form class="form" id="addImageForm" name="addImageForm" action="addImage.php" onsubmit="return validateAddImage();" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `action` attribute with the name of your PHP page, and have the `validateAddImage` method as an `onsubmit` event.

Answer (score 1):

Change the action attribute to the address of the php script you're posting to.
Call the javascript function in an onsubmit attribute instead of action.  But you'll have to prefix it with a return statement.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="your/script.php" id="addImageForm" name="addImageForm" onsubmit=return javascript:validateAddImage()>
```

That way if validateAddImage() returns false, the form won't be submitted.  But if it returns true it will.