# javascript form validation onclick if successful go to next page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

trying to set up form validation on a php page with javascript.

**my javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(){
        var name = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var production = document.getElementById("production").value;
        var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;

        if(name == "" || email == "" || production == "null"){
            alert("All fields are required!");
            return false;
        }
        else if(!(email).match(emailReg){
            alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("firstForm").submit;
        }
    }

</script>
```

**my php code of the form:**

```
echo    '<form action="bookingCont.php" id="firstForm" method="GET" class="booking">
            <p class="formLine">Full Name:&nbsp<input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName"></p>
            <p class="formLine">Email:&nbsp<input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>';            

    echo    '<p class="formLine">Production: <select id="production" name="production">';
    echo                                    '</select></p>
            <p class="formLine"><input type="submit" value="Show Me Dates!" onclick="validate()"></p>
            </form>';
```

there's some unimportant code where i fill in the select options that i've omitted here.  The issue i'm having is that when i click submit i want the page to run this validate() function and display error messages if the validation fails and submit the form and move on to the next page if the validation is successful.  Under the current setup that's not happening :/ the function doesnt seem to get called at all and it just moves onto the next page...

Comment: With modern HTML5 you can do most of this without any javascript at all ?

Comment: please enlighten me @adeneo :)

Comment: There's the `required` attribute that can be set on elements, that stops your form from submitting, then there's the `email` type that will validate your input automagically etc.

Comment: this was really helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 solutions here.

1. If you already use jQuery, then go for the `e.preventDefault()` in the submit listener.
2. Add a `onsubmit="validate();"` attribute in the form element, and remove `onclick` from the button. If returned true, it will submit.
3. Change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. With another type, the only way to submit it is by javascript.

Hope you find the best fit for you.

Comment: So i did this and the form doesn't submit if the fields are empty, which is good, but no alerts appear, which is not so good :P

Comment: Does it submit if the fields are filled out? :)

Comment: just checked this - it does not :/

Comment: We would be of more help if you made a functioning jsfiddle or in-post functioning code of the problem that we could fix. It seems there are more problems than just the submit thing. Might be problem with variable type or regex as well that keeps the alerts from firing?

Comment: `(!(email).match(emailReg))` you are lacking a `)` there

Comment: how do i go about making a jsfiddle?

Comment: I made you a [head start here](http://jsfiddle.net/5j65muq2/) I commented out the regex, because it caused an error (Invalid regular expression: /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/: Range out of order in character class).

Comment: so i changed my code to be that same as what you've done in the jsfiddle, and i dont get any alerts popping up :/ pulling my hair out over this

Comment: the regex was really messing things up, fixed it all now, thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Knowing you used an input of type "submit", I would just do the following:

```
$( "#firstForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
    var name = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var production = document.getElementById("production").value;
    var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if(name == "" || email == "" || production == "null"){
        alert("All fields are required!");
        return false; // prevent form submission
    }
    else if(!(email).match(emailReg){
        alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
        return false; // prevent form submission
    }
    else{
        return true; // good to go!
    }
});
```

Comment: so i just replace my function validate() with this code?

Comment: I believe it was a javascript question, not jQuery. Is there a preventDefault pure javascript solution?

Comment: @J.Kite: No, you also need to add a jQuery library to your page. If you use it already, then this is a good solution, but if this is the only thing you need it for, then I would go with the `type=button` solution instead.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this article explaining another method:
[Form submit to run javascript and then post to php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454087/form-submit-to-run-javascript-and-then-post-to-php-script)

```
<form class="form" name="form" action="processing.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Basicly add a onsubmit tag in to your form. If validate() returns true, it will send out the form

EDIT: in your function validate(), you should put the error handling (e.g. display a "error box" on your page with the error inside

EDIT2:
Your javascript should be changed into

```
function validate(){
    var name = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var production = document.getElementById("production").value;
    var emailReg = /^([w-.]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if(name == "" || email == "" || production == "null"){
        alert("All fields are required!");
        return false;
    }
    else if(!(email).match(emailReg)){
        alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then your form should look like:

```
<form name="form" action="processing.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <!-- Put your input tags here with the correct ids -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I hope that this makes everything clear

Comment: could you elaborate on that? im not sure what you mean

Comment: Basicly, when you click on your button, the form will be send to "processing.php". WIth the onsubmit tag, the form will first execute that javascript function. 

So, if that function returns true (e.g. if ( username == valid ) { return true; } ), then and only then the form will be send. If it returns false, the form will not be send

Comment: sorry i meant elaborate on your edit, i understood the first part :)

Comment: I edited my post with more code. I hope that that helps you

Comment: made all these changes, still no alerts popping up :/